# Laravel user address scenario - HasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

User table (`users`):

- id
- name
- password

User address table (`user_addreses`):

- id
- user_id
- city_id

Cities table (`cities`):

- id
- name

User Model:

```php
public function address() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAddreses');
}
```

How can I get the city at this address from the `cities` table?

`UserAddreses` model:

```php
public function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}
```

> Error: Property [city] does not exist on this collection instance.

The command I need to run:

```php
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($user->address->city);
```

Comment: Users have many addresses. Therefore `$user->address` would be a collection of addresses. U need to loop through the addresses. You could have done `$user->address->city` if users had one address each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that `$user->address` returns a `collection`, so you have to iterate over each one to get the `->city`...

```php
$cities = $user->address->map(function (Address $address) {
    return $address->city;
});
```